# C++ erasing part of the end of a vector without reallocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

Looking through the C++ vector documents, pop_back() is a function that will not cause a reallocation of the vector's data. However, this only works for removing one member of the vector. I am trying to find a way to erase multiple members from the end of a vector. Originally I thought I would call pop_back() in a small for loop but I was wandering if there was a more convenient function that would do this for me?

Edit:
The [Cplusplus vector erase() reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) is not as clear as it should be as pointed out by juanchopanza. It is why I originally discarded using erase(). Erase afterall, works well.

Comment: See [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).

Comment: @juanchopanza Erase causes a reallocation.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm reading here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/ "erasing elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new positions."

Comment: That is an unfortunately misleading quote (the cplusplus.com one). If it re-allocated, it could not maintain the validity of iterators and references to elements before the first erased one.

Comment: @sgtHale: first you confound reallocation (which is not done with `erase`) and the possible move/copy of the element past the last element removed. *relocate* is different than *reallocate*.

Comment: @juanchopanza That is misleading indeed. Alright thanks I understand now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `vector::erase`. It will not reallocate memory.

If your erased range does not extend to the end of the container, it WILL re-locate the end elements. That means the ending elements will be `move`d to their proper spot in memory which likely incurs a data copy. That is not the same as a re-allocation of the backing store. If your ending element is `myVector.end()`, no relocation will need to occur.

Answer (score 5):

You can use member functions `erase`. The vector will not be reallocated because according to the C++ Standard, e.g. [C++17 n4659 standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4659.pdf) 26.3.11.5 [vector.modifiers] "vector modifiers":

> ```
> iterator erase(const_iterator position);
> iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
> ```
>
> 3 Effects: **Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase**.

The bold part of the quote means that the vector will not be reallocated.